# Mapear desde Java a Mongo un objeto con estructura personalizada

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Estoy usando una base de datos Mongo y el *backend* con Java Spring. Originalmente tenía esta estructura:

```
"defaultActivation":{
    "accounts": ["500026", "500027"]
}
```

Y lo mapeaba con la siguiente estructura en Java:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> defaultActivation;
```

Pero ahora la estructura es un poco más compleja:

```
"defaultActivation":{
    "accounts": ["500026", "500027"],
    "paymentsModel": {
        "TSP": ["CO", "AR"],
        "PSP": ["CO"]
    }
}"
```

¿Cómo puedo mapear esta nueva estructura, debería crear otro modelo en Java?

Comment: En lugar de generar una estructura nueva "a mano", ¿has considerado utilizar una biblioteca para lectura de objetos JSON? [Esta pregunta en SO en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) y sus respuestas contienen recomendaciones y ligas útiles para ese fin.

Comment: Yo, por mi parte, he usado [JSON Simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) y funciona bastante bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar Gson para este tipo de cosas, en concreto tu problema puede ser planteado de la siguiente manera:

Tienes este Json

```
"defaultActivation":{
    "accounts": ["500026", "500027"],
    "paymentsModel": {
        "TSP": ["CO", "AR"],
        "PSP": ["CO"]
    }
}"
```

Deberías crear un objeto (clase) `PaymentModel` con los atributos `TSP` y `PSP` que son de tipo array.
Para el objeto padre deberías crear una clase `DefaultActivation` con los atributos `account` de tipo array y el otro atributo sería de tipo `PaymentModel`

Con una instancia de Gson solo deberás realizar una llamada a

```
gson.fromJson(json, DefaultActivation.class);
```